# Can we get number of chromeosdevices using google API

Tags: python, django, google-api

I'm wondering is there an option to get exact number of devices from googleAPI like a parameter or something, because currently we can only filter and search for a device and get max 200 devices per page, and if I would like to know how many devices there are how I can do that?
I need this for my pagination, I cannot go through every single page and make 100 requests because it would be too much time consuming, for example if you have 10k devices, you can only get 200 per page(request) that's like calling API 50 times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Get Request All Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102813/python-get-request-all-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Admin Reports API
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/cros

Comment: Seems promising I will check it, thanks.